# CS50 PSET4 edge function not filtering edge and corner - red pixel values correctly

Tags: c, image-processing, cs50, edge-detection, sobel

I am trying to write a function for edge detection in a image using Sobel operator. This is a part of Problem Set 4 - filter(more) problem from the CS50 course. Link [here](https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2022/psets/4/filter/more/) (edge part only).

The function written is filtering the middle pixels of the image correctly but **not giving the desired output for the edge and border pixels that too surprisingly for Red pixel values only** , rest of them are correct.

I have checked the code manually , debugged it several times but still couldn't find the bug. Any help will be deeply appreciated.

Thank you.

> Here is the code for the edge function.

```
// Detect edges
void edges(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{

    // Array for storing corresponding gx values of the pixels.
    RGBTRIPLE(*gx)[width] = calloc(height, width * sizeof(RGBTRIPLE));
    if (gx == NULL)
    {
        printf("Not enough memory to store blur pixels.\n");
        return;
    }

    // Array for storing corresponding gy values of the pixels.
    RGBTRIPLE(*gy)[width] = calloc(height, width * sizeof(RGBTRIPLE));
    if (gy == NULL)
    {
        printf("Not enough memory to store blur pixels.\n");
        return;
    }


    for (int row = 0; row < height; row++)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < width; col++)
        {
            Gx(row, col, height, width, image, gx);
            Gy(row, col, height, width, image, gy);
        }
    }

    for (int row = 0; row < height; row++)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < width; col++)
        {
            image[row][col].rgbtBlue = r_sqrt_sum(gx[row][col].rgbtBlue, gy[row][col].rgbtBlue);
            image[row][col].rgbtGreen = r_sqrt_sum(gx[row][col].rgbtGreen, gy[row][col].rgbtGreen);
            image[row][col].rgbtRed = r_sqrt_sum(gx[row][col].rgbtRed, gy[row][col].rgbtRed);

        }
    }

    free(gx);
    free(gy);
    return;
}
```

> Code for the Gx and Gy functions.

```
void Gx(int row, int col, int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE matrix[height][width], RGBTRIPLE new_matrix[height][width])
// This function will return Gx value of a given pixel.
{
    float Blue = 0;
    float Green = 0;
    float Red = 0;

    for (int i = -1; i < 2; i++)
    {
        for (int j = -1; j < 2; j++)
        {
            // for rows and columns out of range.
            if ((i + row) < 0 || (i + row >= height) || (j + col) < 0 || (j + col >= width))
            {
                continue;
            }

            // for (-1,-1) and (1,-1)
            else if ((i == -1 && j == -1) || (i == 1 && j == -1))
            {
                Blue += matrix[i + row][j + col].rgbtBlue * -1;
                Green += matrix[i + row][j + col].rgbtGreen * -1;
                Red += matrix[i + row][j + col].rgbtRed * -1;
            }

            // for (0,-1)
            else if ((i == 0 && j == -1))
            {
                Blue += matrix[i + row][j + col].rgbtBlue * -2;
                Green += matrix[i + row][j + col].rgbtGreen * -2;
                Red += matrix[i + row][j + col].rgbtRed * -2;
            }

            // for (-1, 0) , (0, 0), (1, 0)
            else if ((i == -1 && j == 0) || (i == 0 && j == 0) || (i == 1 && j == 0))
            {
                Blue += matrix[i + row][j + col].rgbtBlue * 0;
                Green += matrix[i + row][j + col].rgbtGreen * 0;
                Red += matrix[i + row][j + col].rgbtRed * 0;
            }

            // for (0, 1)
            else if ((i == 0 && j == 1))
            {
                Blue += matrix[i + row][j + col].rgbtBlue * 2;
                Green += matrix[i + row][j + col].rgbtGreen * 2;
                Red += matrix[i + row][j + col].rgbtRed * 2;
            }

            // for (-1,1) and (1,1)
            else if ((i == -1 && j == 1) || (i == 1 && j == 1))
            {
                Blue += matrix[i + row][j + col].rgbtBlue * 1;
                Green += matrix[i + row][j + col].rgbtGreen * 1;
                Red += matrix[i + row][j + col].rgbtRed * 1;
            }
        }
    }

    new_matrix[row][col].rgbtBlue = fabsf(Blue);
    new_matrix[row][col].rgbtGreen = fabsf(Green);
    new_matrix[row][col].rgbtRed = fabsf(Red);
}


void Gy(int row, int col, int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE matrix[height][width], RGBTRIPLE new_matrix[height][width])
// This function will return Gy value of a given pixel.
{
    float Blue = 0;
    float Green = 0;
    float Red = 0;

    for (int i = -1; i < 2; i++)
    {
        for (int j = -1; j < 2; j++)
        {
            // for rows and columns out of range.
            if ((i + row) < 0 || (i + row >= height) || (j + col) < 0 || (j + col >= width))
            {
                continue;
            }

            // for (-1,-1) and (-1,1)
            else if ((i == -1 && j == -1) || (i == -1 && j == 1))
            {
                Blue += matrix[i + row][j + col].rgbtBlue * -1;
                Green += matrix[i + row][j + col].rgbtGreen * -1;
                Red += matrix[i + row][j + col].rgbtRed * -1;
            }

            // for (-1, 0)
            else if ((i == -1 && j == 0))
            {
                Blue += matrix[i + row][j + col].rgbtBlue * -2;
                Green += matrix[i + row][j + col].rgbtGreen * -2;
                Red += matrix[i + row][j + col].rgbtRed * -2;
            }

            // for (0, -1) , (0, 0), (0, 1)
            else if ((i == 0 && j == -1) || (i == 0 && j == 0) || (i == 0 && j == 1))
            {
                // printf("for (%d, %d) considering (%d, %d) and using -1 \n", row, col, row+i, col+j);
                Blue += matrix[i + row][j + col].rgbtBlue * 0;
                Green += matrix[i + row][j + col].rgbtGreen * 0;
                Red += matrix[i + row][j + col].rgbtRed * 0;
            }

            // for (1, 0)
            else if ((i == 1 && j == 0))
            {
                Blue += matrix[i + row][j + col].rgbtBlue * 2;
                Green += matrix[i + row][j + col].rgbtGreen * 2;
                Red += matrix[i + row][j + col].rgbtRed * 2;
            }

            // for (1,-1) and (1,1)
            else if ((i == 1 && j == -1) || (i == 1 && j == 1))
            {
                Blue += matrix[i + row][j + col].rgbtBlue * 1;
                Green += matrix[i + row][j + col].rgbtGreen * 1;
                Red += matrix[i + row][j + col].rgbtRed * 1;
            }
        }
    }

    new_matrix[row][col].rgbtBlue = fabsf(Blue);
    new_matrix[row][col].rgbtGreen = fabsf(Green);
    new_matrix[row][col].rgbtRed = fabsf(Red);
}
```

> Code for the r_sqrt_sum function.

```
int r_sqrt_sum(float a, float b)
// Return rounded sqrt of sum of squared a and b.
{
    float x = round(sqrt((a*a + b*b)));

    if (x > 255) return 255;

    else return x;
}
```

Comment: Look closer at the cs50 checker website. There should be a description what test case failed. There you should also find the pixel data that wasa used for the test and what your result was. Take these input values and feed it into your code while debugging.

Comment: When you "debugged [your code] several times", at which point did you first notice that something is wrong? Which variable shows a wrong value? What input did you use?

Comment: Without deeper inspection I would assume your approach using an array to store sums for `Gx` and `Gy` is broken. It can only hold 8 bits per color. Your sums could be larger: `new_matrix[row][col].rgbtBlue = fabsf(Blue);` Proper debugging also includes verifying calculations and compare stored values with expected values.

Comment: Thanks @Gerhardh bro , you pointed out the correct error , after correction the program is giving desired outputs.

Answer (score 0):

So the problem which I was stuck on for so long is finally solved.
Turns out in the above code (in the Gx and Gy functions) I was appending the values of green , blue , red into the new_matrix which was RGBTRIPLE type. It could only take upto 8 bits while the value of the floats may be larger than that.
For that issue I defined a new structure :

```
typedef struct
{
    float  rgbtBlu;
    float  rgbtGree;
    float  rgbtRe;
} __attribute__((__packed__))
RGBFTRIPLE;
```

And changed the new_matrix() type from RGBTRIPLE to RGBFTRIPLE thus making it possible for larger values to be taken.
This solved the problem.

Thanks to the whole community for responding to the several queries and clearing my doubts.

Comment: As you only use that struct internally, there is no need to use a packed struct.